# Joining a table to itself based on a "connection" table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`items` table:

```
id      title       unique_flat_title
---------------------------------------------
1       post 1      post_1
2       post 2      post_2
3       category 1  category_1
4       post 3      post_3
5       post 4      post_4
6       category 2  category_2
7       post 5      post_5
```

`item_connection` table:

```
post_id     category_id
----------------------------------
1           3
1           6
5           6
7           3
4           3
4           6
```

I'd like to print all the items that are connected to another item where the `unique_flat_title` is `category_2`. Is that possible? Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:

[Here's an example on the "connections"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5BJC.png)

So let's say I need the list of posts where `unique_flat_title` is `category_1`.

Then I'd need the following list as a result:

```
category_flat_title     post_id     post_title
------------------------------------------------------  
category_1              1           post 1
category_1              7           post 5
category_1              4           post 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "connected to another item"? Do you want to do something more than print out items in category 2?

Comment: How are the items connected?  `items.id` is equal to `category_id`?

Comment: [Here's an example on the "connections"](http://i.imgur.com/1lWkLHY.png) 


So let's say I need the list of posts where `unique_flat_title` is `category_1`.


Then I'd need the following list as a result:


`category_flat_title  post_id  post_title
    ---------------------------------------------- 
    category_1    1   post 1
    category_1    7   post 5
    category_1    4   post 3`

Comment: Edited my original post, sorry for the unformatted comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the "items" table to "items_connection", using the ID from the first to match the CATGEORY_ID of the second.
Then, you can join this to the "items" table again, using the POST_ID of the second to match with the ID of the third. 
it would look like this:

```
SELECT A.unique_flat_title As category_flat_title
     , C.id As post_id , C.unique_flat_title As post_title
from items A 
join item_connection B on  B.category_id = A.id
join items C on C.id=B.post_id
```